# Handling selected item changed in mvvm from a user control

Tags: mvvm, selecteditem

I have a user control defined in a separate project (To reuse) which has two comboboxes and a button. I will be using this user control in other projects. The user control has a view model class. This view model class handles selected item changed in the combobox and also has a command delegate to handle the button click.

Now my question is when I use this user control within another control in another project I want an event to be raised within this owning control as well whenever a new item is selected in the combobox. Also, when a button is clicked in the resuable control I want that event to be raised in my owning control as well so that I can execute some additional logic. Can somebody suggest which is the best way to handle this?

Thanks,
Ranjith

Comment: why dont you use dependency properties within your usercontrol? so everyone who wanna use it can bind to these DPs

Comment: I used Action delegate to solve my issue. 
Apparently, whenever selecteditem is changed which is captured in the view model it raises another event called SelectionChanged (Action delegate) if somebody has subscribed. 
My other question does it make sense to use reactive extensions for this case?